# Issues with Next.js/React forwardRef() function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

While developing a website for a class (I used a youtube tutorial to build the site), I am having this error show up in the console:

[image]

Although the site renders locally, this causes issues when I try to deploy it, as you can imagine. So I found the documentation for the React.forwardRef() and I implemented it like this in my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/PizzaCard.module.css";
import Link from 'next/link';

const PizzaCard = React.forwardRef(({pizza}, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref}/>>(
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Link href={`/product/${pizza._id}`} passHref>
      <Image src={pizza.img} alt="" width="500" height="500"/>
      </Link>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>{pizza.title}</h1>
        <span className={styles.price}>${pizza.prices[0]}</span>
        <p className={styles.desc}>
            {pizza.desc}
        </p>
    </div>
  );
});
export default PizzaCard;
```

And this in my PizzaList file:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "../styles/PizzaList.module.css";
import PizzaCard from "./PizzaCard";


const PizzaList = React.forwardRef(({pizzaList}, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref}/>> (
    <div className = {styles.container}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>The Mellowist Pizza in Town!</h1>
        <p className={styles.desc}>
            Mellow Yellow Pizzaria is a local Family Owned business providing
            the community with tasty pizza made with Heart and Soul!
        </p>
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          {pizzaList.map((pizza) => (
            <PizzaCard key={pizza._id} pizza={pizza} />
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
})

export default PizzaList
```

And here is where PizzaList is called:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import Add from "../components/Add";
import AddButton from "../components/AddButton";
import Featured from "../components/Featured";
import PizzaList from "../components/PizzaList";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home({pizzaList, admin}) {
  const [close, setClose] = useState(true)
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Mellow Yellow Pizzaria</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Created by Yellow project team at CTU" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Featured/>
      {admin && <AddButton setClose={setClose}/>}
      <PizzaList pizzaList={pizzaList} />
      {!close && <Add setClose={setClose}/>}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) =>{
  const myCookie = ctx.req?.cookies || ""
  let admin = false
  
  if(myCookie.token === process.env.TOKEN){
    admin = true
  }
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products")
  return{
    props:{
      pizzaList:res.data,
      admin,
    }
  }
}
```

Although this made the console errors go away, now my pizza products do not display, as you can see:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong? If you need me to post more of my code, please let me know and I will, I'm not sure what all you'd need to see.

EDIT:

Here is my original code before adding the forwardRef()...this is the code that gives me the console errors in the first screenshot, I added the forwardRef() to PizzaCard and PizzaList because those are 2 spots that the console suggested I check (the list of "at ..." in the console window)

PizzaCard:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/PizzaCard.module.css";
import Link from 'next/link';

const PizzaCard = ({pizza}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Link href={`/product/${pizza._id}`} passHref>
      <Image src={pizza.img} alt="" width="500" height="500"/>
      </Link>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>{pizza.title}</h1>
        <span className={styles.price}>${pizza.prices[0]}</span>
        <p className={styles.desc}>
            {pizza.desc}
        </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PizzaCard;
```

PizzaList:

```
import styles from "../styles/PizzaList.module.css";
import PizzaCard from "./PizzaCard";


const PizzaList = ({pizzaList}) => {
  return (
    <div className = {styles.container}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>The Mellowist Pizza in Town!</h1>
        <p className={styles.desc}>
            Mellow Yellow Pizzaria is a local Family Owned business providing
            the community with tasty pizza made with Heart and Soul!
        </p>
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          {pizzaList.map((pizza) => (
            <PizzaCard key={pizza._id} pizza={pizza} />
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PizzaList
```

Here is a link to my github with all of the code:
https://github.com/InvisibleH3R0/mellowyellowpizzaria

***Original Issue Fixed***

So the fix for the ref issue was to wrap the image (in the first set of code I posted) in `<a></a>`

But now...when I load the site (locally) the homepage starts off just white, if I refresh the page it comes up...but when I inspect the page when first loading, it shows a internal server (500) error:

[image]

This leads me to believe the issue lies in the api/products or api/options code, that is where the GET methods are

Comment: Why are you even using refs? You don't seem to do anything with the refs anywhere (you don't even pass refs to your components). If you don't have some omitted reason for using refs, I suggest you revert your code to the previous state and find out from where that error message is coming.

Comment: Also, what's with the initial `<input />>`? What's your intention with that? I would think you'd run into errors based on several things there (extra `>` at the end, also multiple elements workout wrapping in a `Fragment` :)

Comment: Well, the reason I'm using anything is because it was either A. in the tutorial video I watched, or B. from the documentation/tutorials on React.forwardRef()...I'll upload the original code and maybe that'll help

Comment: For the record, I'm getting my degree in cyber security, so why I'm taking a full blown developer class, I don't know, lol...so yeah, I'm a little dumb in this arena :/

Comment: So given the current state of the code in the repo... You still get an error about refs passed to an functional component?

Comment: Yup, that first screenshot that I posted is with the code currently in the repo

Comment: The problem is not in your code, it's the `Image` component that doesn't accept the `ref` that `Link` is trying to set when `passHref` is used. The problem is described here for example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20434, try wrapping the `Image` in a `<a>` which will accept the `ref`.

Comment: First, you're my hero, haha. ..the <a> fixed the ref error..but, as it goes in the coding world, fix one issue and reveal another...now when I load the website up, the homepage shows up as white again, but the console is just throwing a 500 (page not found) error, however if I refresh the page it comes up. The problem seems to be in the api/products code somewhere:                                                                                                                 
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products',
      data: undefined

Comment: Seems like an unrelated problem so then you should probably make a new question. Also, 500 is not page not found (404) but internal server error.

Comment: yeah, I did post a new question and that was solved :)